# Generate an serial number for primary key using sql e.g 16-001 and auto increment on every new entry 16-002 and so on

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a function but it throws an conversion exception.

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '16-001' to data type int.

This statement causes the error. +'-'+  RIGHT(@pId,3)+1

```
Create Function NextProjectNumber() 
Returns char(6) 
As 
Begin 

    Declare @pId varchar(50) , @pYear int, @serial varchar(3), @currYear int

    SELECT 
        @pId = ProjectId 
    from 
        [JobPortalDb].[dbo].[Projects] 
    Where 
        ProjectId= (Select max(ProjectId) from [JobPortalDb].[dbo].[Projects])

    Set @currYear = (SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), year(GETDATE()), 1),2)) --SELECT @pId,@year

    If @pId IS NULL 
        Set @pId = (SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), year(GETDATE()), 1),2))+'-001' 
    Else 
        Set @pYear = SUBSTRING(@pId, 1, 2)

    If @pYear = @currYear 
        set @pId =(SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), year(GETDATE()), 1),2)) +'-'+ RIGHT(@pId,3)+1

    If @currYear > @pYear 
        set @pId = (SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), year(GETDATE()), 1),2)) +'-001'

    Return @pId 
End
```

Comment: Always check for types - E.g. Use `CAST(CAST(RIGHT(@pId,3) AS int)+1 AS varchar)` ;).

Comment: Msg 1035, Level 15, State 10, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.

Comment: thank you http://stackoverflow.com/users/4519059/sha-t

Comment: after casting result is changed to 16-2 and it must be 16-002

Comment: I think you can use `RIGHT('000' + CAST(CAST(RIGHT(@pId,3) AS int)+1 AS varchar), 3)` to format that ;).

Answer (score 0):

I checked with static value and its fine, see below.

This means and the error suggest that in projectid (@pId) you have a string value and unable to concatenate with numeric value, if yes then simply use 'Cast'. I will check, just give the project ID.

```
Create Function NextProjectNumber() 
Returns char(6) 
As 
Begin 

    Declare @pId varchar(50) = 1 , @pYear int, @serial varchar(3), @currYear int

    --SELECT 
    --  @pId = ProjectId 
    --from 
    --  [JobPortalDb].[dbo].[Projects] 
    --Where 
    --  ProjectId= (Select max(ProjectId) from [JobPortalDb].[dbo].[Projects])

    Set @currYear = (SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), year(GETDATE()), 1),2)) --SELECT @pId,@year

    If @pId IS NULL 
        Set @pId = (SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), year(GETDATE()), 1),2))+'-001' 
    Else 
        Set @pYear = SUBSTRING(@pId, 1, 2)

    If @pYear = @currYear 
        set @pId =(SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), year(GETDATE()), 1),2)) +'-'+ RIGHT(@pId,3)+1

    If @currYear > @pYear 
        set @pId = (SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), year(GETDATE()), 1),2)) +'-001'

    Return @pId 
End

select dbo.NextProjectNumber
```

Output is last statment ( `select dbo.NextProjectNumber` ) is:

```
16-001
```